# What's the Jira markdown code for inline tag like appearance?

Tags: markdown, jira

I could use an inline tag like appearance in Jira descriptions and comments.
Yes I googled, and yes I found this is actually a most wanted feature that doesn't seem to be officially implemented (anymore?).

However I found exactly what I'm looking for in an image on a blog from years ago; https://blog.servicerocket.com/adoption/blog/2015/01/using-markup-in-jira-comments

Sadly the article just misses the explanation of that piece of formatting.

At the bottom of this image it shows 'I, Breakfast-bot' as 
[image: Example image from the above blog post showing the tag like appearance]

Has this disappeared from Jira or does anyone know how this is or was written in markdown?

This is not in the official markdown information pages of Jira.
I tried already with the 'monospaced' formatting but this seems only to have an impact on the fontface not the highlight or 'tag'border.

- For monospaced formatting {{monospaced}} is used according to Jira.
- The {code} or {panel} tags are not rendered inline.

I expect to have a similar 'tag'like notation (like in the picture):

- Monospaced fontface
- Inline formatted
- Slightly rounded border
- Subtle highlighted background

Comment: My guess is that this is just the standard {{ }} monospace tags, but that the default Jira stylesheet for their formatting has changed between when that blog post was published (2005) and now.

Comment: I think you're right Scott, though Mikey's post was 2015 not 2005.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I contacted the original author of the document I referenced. 
He not only answered but looked up the markdown code he used to produce that line.

```
* We need to get the {{I, Breakfast-bot}} class into
```

He tested the same markdown code {{}} on Jira Cloud. It still is used but hasn't got the same rendering anymore. The border and background or the tag like appearance if you will is not any longer there.

Looks like your suspicion had some ground Scott Dudley. But with this answer we have confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Jira doesn't have any markdown feature out of the box. Looking at the screenshot you've got from ServiceRocket's blog, it looks similar to a feature made available by an archived plugin by Atlassian Labs, which I have experimented back in Jira 5: [Markdown for Jira](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/archive/1210742).

Nevertheless, official feature request for Markdown is tracked [here](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-37594).

Comment: I'm very much in doubt that it was possible due to a plugin especially because the blogpost's point was to show jira's markdown and not some deeper customization. Bit I could be wrong of course. 

The feature request link is about something else markdown related not about having the ability to use an inline code-like markdown.

The clearest request I could find is one of atlassian's hipchat software. Where it has been stated clearly that it won't be done. https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/HCPUB-607

Answer (score 0):

I can't find out what version of Jira I have* *but* in my version I can hit Shift-Cmd-M with some text selected and get inline code that way. It's a font style, in the overflow menu next to bold and italic. The `{{code here}}` markup doesn't work.

It's really obnoxious that Jira won't get on the Markdown train.

* it's Feb 2022 now and this looks like a very current version